# Multi-Device Hybrid App project is not the same as a Cordova Project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm trying to get my head around the way Visual Studio - Multi-Device Hybrid App project lays out a file structure vs how Cordova (PhoneGap) lays out a file structure.

I'm a bit confused because I thought this VS extension was for building phone Gap applications

Here is the comparison of the file structures between Visual Studio (MDHA) and the counter part from Cordova (PhoneGap).

> > cordova create hello au.com.IdeasMen KeepInContact

The Cordova Create command builds a file structure like this

[image]

VS project Multi-Device Hybrid App looks like this

[image]

This second structure looks a little like the content of the Cordova WWW folder, but even then it is only similar not the same.

Comment: You have to compare the Android generated project that is under platforms folder. Generate this structure by command: cordova platform add android

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's distinguish between Cordova and PhoneGap as separate things. Cordova is the open source implementation and while it shares a core with PhoneGap, there are always chances that Adobe could do something "special" with PhoneGap to enhance their service.

Secondly, about the nature of the project structure. While Multi-Device Hybrid Apps tries hard to maintain the same look and feel as that of a Cordova project, there are certainly design and cosmetic decisions that have been taken to make it more usable for developers. Some might say that maintaining the exact same structure helps the familiarity argument, and that is also a valid point.

The most important thing to remember is that whatever the structure looks like inside Visual Studio, at the heart of it, MDHA is not performing any proprietary actions with the project. It is only an enabler to let developers build with the Cordova CLI by providing a GUI to work with. Under the covers, it still renders the project into a Cordova like project.

That, and all the value add features like setting up your machine, developing and debugging, adding services, connecting to emulators and building and publishing.

Disclosure: I'm a Program Manager on the Visual Studio Cordova Tools product team.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, it makes a lot of sense and at the moment I am going through the AngularJsToDo example and anything else I can get my hands on learn how this all fits together.

Comment: My big problem with this structure, is that once I have done the tutorials, I actually have to start working with an existing PhoneGap application that presently is used by others in GIT Repo and maintained on Linux environments. I will not have the luxury of dictating the file structure, I must confirm to what they have.

Comment: I'm wondering if I have an existing PhoneGap application, is there a way of setting up MDHA so that it behaves and outputs files to the standard PhoneGap structure

Comment: In regards to this statment >> "Secondly, about the nature of the project structure. While Multi-Device Hybrid Apps tries hard to maintain the same look and feel as that of a Cordova project" It does not look to me like the MDHA structure is even remotely like a PhoneGap structure? I've got an app running, I don't really understand why it works because it does not see to follow any of the PhoneGap conventions

Comment: I'm working on a project that was created with the Cordova CLI. I'm able to use Visual Studio, I just can't build from inside Visual Studio - I have to go to node.js to do that.

Comment: When you say you can use Visual Studio, do you mean you can use it to edit the files? I too can edit the files with Visual Studio, but I don't the point of the MDHA project, all the benefits that it provides, compilation, running different emulators, selecting packages is all useless because you have to use their structure which is not the same (not even really all that close) to the Cordova structure, and since I am in an existing enterprise, I can't just change the structure to suit the Microsoft view of the world.